# Unable to create multiple databases with the same name on different SQL Servers in Azure via ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I am using an ARM template to create Azure resources. I've run the template once to create a SQL Server and database in a resource group. It worked fine. When I run it a second time with different parameters, it successfully creates the SQL Server but fails with a vague message for the database.

Excerpt from my ARM template:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
  "kind": "v12.0",
  "name": "[variables('sqlServer_name')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
  "location": "[parameters('resourceLocation')]",
  "tags": "[variables('environmentTags')]",
  "properties": {
    "administratorLogin": "[parameters('sqlServerAdminAccountName')]",
    "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('sqlServerAdminAccountPassword')]",
    "version": "12.0"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "EnableAzureServicesFirewallRule",
      "type": "firewallRules",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlServer_name'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
  "sku": "[variables('databaseSizeSkuMap')[parameters('sqlServerDatabaseSize')]]",
  "kind": "v12.0,user",
  "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServer_name'), '/', variables('sqlServerDatabase_name'))]",
  "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
  "location": "[parameters('resourceLocation')]",
  "tags": "[variables('environmentTags')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlServer_name'))]"
  ]
}
```

The sku is `{ "name": "Free", "tier": "Free" }`.

Running the template results in two separate resource groups each with a SQL Server instance:

### Resource Group Dev

- Server: sql-myappname-dev
- Database: sql-myappname-dev/DbName

### Resource Group Test

- Server: sql-myappname-test
- Database: sql-myappname-test/DbName  <--- Fails to create

## Error message:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 6:21:23 PM - Resource Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases 'sql-myappname-test/DbName' failed with message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: '438f9ade-e84f-4627-acec-1156ea54aa65'"
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

What is the issue here? I've been able to create databases with the same name on separate servers through the Azure Portal. Also, if I delete **Resource Group Dev**, then running the template for **Resource Group Test** succeeds in creating the database.

Comment: retry it? also, you cannot create another sql with the same name

Comment: When I retry, it still fails.There is no problem creating this in the Azure Portal, only when running an ARM template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure only supports one free tier SQL database per region & subscription.

> ## Limitations
>
> This process will allow you to get up to one free Azure
>   SQL database per region.

[Source](http://www.andresnava.com/2017/05/free-azure-sql-database/)

Changing the pricing tier for one of the ARM template parameters files from "Free" to "Basic" allows both databases to be created.

To create a second free tier database, it needs to be created in a different region or subscription.